# FastAPI validation error on response_model

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic, uvicorn

I have an FastAPI server that communicates with another API server (Lumen) to retrieve data, basically it only proxies the routes to the Lumen server.

Inside Lumen routes we have some validation rules and when we pass invalid body request it fails and returns `422` error code and a message.
The problem is that my Fast API endpoint returns a `response_model` for the request in particular, so when a validation error occurs it tries to return the response model and the server fails because the `code` and `message` fields doesn't exist in our response_model

```
@router.post("/products/offers", response_model=OfferSearchResult, operation_id="offer_search")
async def offer_search(
    body: OfferSearchRequest,
    context: AppContext = Depends(get_context),
    max_per_product: Optional[conint(ge=1, le=100)] = Query(None, alias="maxPerProduct"),
    sort_by: Optional[OfferSort] = Query(None, alias="sortBy"),
) -> OfferSearchResult:

    offer_search_result = await OfferService(context).get_offers(body, max_per_product=max_per_product, sort_by=sort_by)
    return offer_search_result
```

I tried to solve this by overriding `validation_exception_handler` but didn't work, how can I return that Lumen's validation error message to return as a fastAPI response?

Comment: You can use `response_model=Union[OfferSearchResult, ErrorResponse]` where `ErrorResponse` describes the expected format if a 422 error occurs. That should allow both models to be returned, and FastAPI will pick the one that suits the returned data. Does that work?